# How can I make this query against a table with over 3 million records faster than 15+ seconds?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have the following query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
    customer_id
FROM
    orders 
WHERE
    "status" IN ( 'authorized', 'paid', 'partially_paid', 'pending')    
GROUP BY 
    customer_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(customer_id) >= 2
```

That yields the following query plan:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=440054.50..516225.43 rows=252557 width=33) (actual time=12206.961..17389.057 rows=457301 loops=1)
  Group Key: customer_id
  Filter: (count(customer_id) >= 2)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 592730
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=440054.50..511174.29 rows=505114 width=41) (actual time=12206.945..16674.249 rows=1615901 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=439054.47..451871.57 rows=252557 width=41) (actual time=12101.661..14862.466 rows=538634 loops=3)
              Group Key: customer_id
              ->  Sort  (cost=439054.47..442484.98 rows=1372204 width=33) (actual time=12101.648..14344.507 rows=1097122 loops=3)
                    Sort Key: customer_id
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 45448kB
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..224124.56 rows=1372204 width=33) (actual time=0.014..1205.188 rows=1097122 loops=3)
                          Filter: ((status)::text = ANY ('{authorized,paid,partially_paid,pending}'::text[]))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 24092
Planning time: 0.101 ms
Execution time: 17434.175 ms
```

The table itself has over 3 million records.

At the end of the day, I'm trying to find all customers that have made 2 or more orders over all-time and am trying to get this query to respond quickly, preferably under a few seconds.

I've tried several approaches but I can't seem to get the execution time to be fast.

Any ideas on how I can improve this?

Comment: What are the indexes you have on the table?

Comment: I would expect an index over `customer_id` to help a lot

Comment: There is an index on customer_id already. As well as status.

Comment: Why do you need to filter on `status`?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are doing a sequential scan, the scan is actually pretty fast (`actual time=0.014..1205.188` milliseconds).  Where you're really getting hit is the sort, which takes `actual time=12101.648..14344.507`.  You're spilling to disk with `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 45448kB`

Try increasing your `work_mem` to a value higher than 48MB, and see if that helps.

Comment: This made a significant improvement in performance. Cut it down to 3 seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a filtered index would speed the query:

```
create index idf_orders_customer_id_status on (customer_id)
    where "status" IN ( 'authorized', 'paid', 'partially_paid', 'pending') ;

SELECT customer_id
FROM orders 
WHERE "status" IN ( 'authorized', 'paid', 'partially_paid', 'pending')    
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: This didn't help the execution time unfortunately. I know using an IN with multiple values can lead to degraded query performance but it is something we have to filter by.

Comment: @john . . . It didn't get rid of the sort for the `order by`, then, I assume.

Comment: actually I think it did but it still used a Seq Scan I presume due to the number of records that the query optimizer still found it more optimal.